# Where i must put hooks in overridable functions?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

Where i must put hooks in overridable functions for better child themes? Inside if statement or outside?

```
if( !function_exists( ovveridable_function() ) {
    function overridable_function() {
        echo 'Test';
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'overridable_function' );
}
```

**OR**

```
if( !function_exists( ovveridable_function() ) {
    function overridable_function() {
        echo 'Test';
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'overridable_function' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Hooked functions don’t need to be pluggable because child themes can already unhook and replace them with `remove_action()`.

The main functions that you’d want to make pluggable are functions that are used in templates i.e. template tags, and those functions aren’t usually hooked, so the placement of `add_action()` isn’t relevant. Even then you probably only need to make them pluggable if they’re used in multiple templates, because otherwise the child theme could just replace the template file.

Answer (score -2):

Try with outside if

```
function overridable_function() {
    echo 'Test';
}
add_action( 'init', 'overridable_function' );
```